# select condition if column value lower than other column

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have a row :

```
id name bag1 bag2 bag3 bag4
1  bob  6    2    3    2
2  tabl 8    7    1    5
3  mum  2    8    9    12
```

wanted return :

```
id name bag1 bag2 bag3 bag4
3  mum  2    8    9    12
```

how to select, **if bag1 is lower than bag2 and bag3**, and it's only based on bag1, because sometimes bag3,bag4-bagX has value and sometimes just null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build an array from the columns to compare and use that:

```
select *
from bags
where bag1 < all (array[bag2,bag3,bag4]);
```

`NULL` values will simply be ignored.

Online example: http://rextester.com/OLFQ16202

Comment: @RubiJihantoro: works with the sample data you have given: http://rextester.com/OLFQ16202  (and "doesn't work is not a valid Postgres error message)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use simple and and conditional operators?

```
select * from yourtable where bag1 < bag2 and bag1 < bag3
```

Comment: says, i have bag3-bag6, how to make it just based on bag1 ?, *it's for dynamic query

Comment: please provide your complete table. I'm not understanding wiht bag3-bag6?

Comment: okay, and how many bag1,2,3 columns do you have in your table?

Comment: up to 9 column of bag*.

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from your_table where bag1<bag2 and bag1<bag3
```